# Training Set Accuracy in Weka

Tags: weka

I'm running some simple classifiers in Weka to test the waters, and I can't find this particular piece of output data.

When using something like a % split, how can I obtain the training set accuracy, and not just the testing set accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use training data to build your model, so it does not make sense at all because you will get a high % of accuracy. And you cannot guide the "fine tuning" with these results because you can get overfitting (do not generalize).

But anyway, you can use the training set to build your model, save it. And once you have it, use your training set as test set with the same model.

You can also click "More Options" and "Output predictions" to know what happened in detail with each instance.

Answer (score 1):

`Weka Explorer` only reports accuracy on testing set when you specify `Percentage split` of your training set.

To get the accuracy on training set you can select `Use training set`, but in this case the entire data will be used (you can split it before using Weka).

In general, testing accuracy is more important because it shows how the algorithm *generalize* and perform with new data. Training accuracy alone is misleading, because it will get better even when the algorithm *overfit* the data